# Is “am” ever proper English without an “I” somewhere before or after it?

Tags: formality, verb-agreement, subjects, personal-pronouns, pronoun-dropping

For a long time, I have been convinced that the use of the word *am* without the word *I* either before or after it is incorrect. For instance, saying *Am going* all by itself.

However, I recently ran a search on it to try and clear up the confusion, but that has left me even more confused than I was to begin with!

Comment: And your search result was?

Comment: Asking whether ok not to have a subject?

Comment: Am a bit confused here ;)

Comment: maybe your initial thoughts on the matter will help to guide the answerer

Answer (score 4):

The pronoun is sometimes omitted in a text in note form. It is required otherwise, and it is usually present in speech.

Comment: Not in American speech, normally. _I'm_ is the normal pronunciation and it tends to be present or absent as a unit, in cases of Conversational Deletion, for instance: _Going to the store_ but _*Am going to the store_. _Am_ always sounds strange when it gets isolated by conjunction reduction: _I have got the bread and am coming home now._ I

Comment: Or, "Forgot the bread and am on my way back to the store."

Answer (score 4):

People will understand what you mean, but the only context in which you'll see it is a hastily written note or text message. In spoken English people would say "I'm ...". In some dialects this may sound like "Ahm", but it still means "I'm". It would definitely look like an error in a formal context.

You *might*  encounter it spoken in a police or similar radio context, which has its own dialect and idiom: "Roger control, am proceeding to location bravo".

Answer (score 1):

One case where we accept "am" with no pronoun is the childish rejoinder "Am not!" or "Am too!". For example, "You're stupid!" "Am not!" or "You're *not* going with us." "Am to!"

This might also happen in an informal note to someone. "Am going shopping. Back soon." I don't think I've ever heard anyone say this out loud, though.

Answer (score -3):

In everyday speech [***pro-drop language***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language) is perfectly acceptable. No more needs to be said on this subject.

Although English does not fall into the category of classic pro-drop languages, pronoun-dropping occurs frequently both in formal and informal usage as the cited entry from wikipedia suggests:

> English is considered a non-pro-drop language. Nonetheless, subject pronouns are almost always dropped in imperative sentences (e.g., Come here). In informal speech, pronouns may sometimes be dropped in other type of sentences, together with some other words, especially copulas and auxiliaries:
>   [Have you] ever been there?
>   [I'm] going to the shops. [[Do] you] want to come [with [me]]?
>   Seen on signs: [I am/We are] out to lunch; [I/we will be] back at 1:00 [P.M].
>   What do you think [of it]? – I like [it]! (the latter only in some dialects)
>   In speech, when pronouns are not dropped, they are more often elided than other words in an utterance.
>   Relative pronouns are often dropped in short restrictive clauses: That's the man [whom] I saw.
>   Note that these elisions are generally restricted to very informal speech and certain fixed expressions, and the rules for their use are complex and vary among dialects.

Comment: Can we have an example of where it is acceptable? And your link is about languages that don't need the pronoun at all, not about dropping it in certain situations.

Comment: the link provided answers all your questions.

Comment: and this very page contains ample good examples:)

Comment: The page you linked to does not touch on the specific example of _am_. Yes, it is sometimes dropped in conversation but not very often, it is more a feature of texting than speaking.

Comment: what?? Excluding I is still pro drop. Please tell me what is wrong with the example given below by @John Lawler

Comment: Absolutely nothing, good point. I was thinking of less complete sentences like "Am on my way back" which I would not _say_ though would likely text.

Comment: But the link you give has: 'English is considered a non-pro-drop language.' and  'In informal speech, pronouns **may sometimes** be dropped in ... sentences.' This doesn't sound exactly the same as being  'perfectly acceptable'.

Comment: I wouldn't dispute that - what is your point?

Comment: I've added to the comment.

Comment: you seem to have missed the qualifier 'in everyday speech'

Comment: No I don't seem to have missed it. You seem to be missing the relative unusualness ('may sometimes') of the dropping of the pronoun even in informal (everyday) speech (I'm quoting from the link you give here). Relatively unusual constructions are often **not** perfectly acceptable, and a cavalier 'No more needs to be said on this subject' is certainly unacceptable.

Comment: What @Edwin said. The text of this answer gives the misleading impression that *pro-drop language* is a recognised variant *within* English. But as the link points out, the term applies to languages, not variations within a language. And it says English is ***not*** a "pro-drop language", which accords with most people's perception that dropping the pronoun isn't normally acceptable (except in already-stilted contexts like txt msgs).

Comment: The text doesn't say anything like you suggest. The answer quite succinctly points out that pro drop tendencies in everyday speech are acceptable.

Comment: Quite apart from that, why there is such objection to this usage when the linked wikipedia article provides ample illustration in the 'English Language' section for this practice is mystifying.

Comment: My objection is not so much to the usage (though I rarely use it myself) but to your 'perfectly acceptable' claim, your dismissive 'no more needs to be said', and your misuse of the term 'pro-drop language'.

Comment: this judgement is clearly based on a distorted interpretation, not just of my answer but, still quite mystifyingly, of the resource cited. Am done with this peskiness tbh.